# how to setup ingress nginx controller in a private network

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a k8s cluster with master (controll plane) @ 192.168.1.66 and only one worker node @ 192.18.1.67
All node have no public IP address.

I'm trying to deploy ingress nginx controller per https://devopscube.com/setup-ingress-kubernetes-nginx-controller/

I just arrieved at step : 'Create Ingress Controller & Admission Controller Services'

But the 'ingress-nginx-controller' LoadBalancer got pending External IP.

```
bino@corobalap  ~/k8nan/ingresnginx/nginx-ingress-controller/manifests   main  kubectl --namespace ingress-nginx get services -o wide 
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE     SELECTOR
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.100.42.100   <pending>     80:30482/TCP,443:31697/TCP   6m32s   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.106.242.13   <none>        443/TCP                      6m32s   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
```

Kindly please what I need to read or do.

Sincerely,

-bino-

```
bino@corobalap  ~/k8nan  kubectl describe service ingress-nginx-controller --namespace ingress-nginx
Name:                     ingress-nginx-controller
Namespace:                ingress-nginx
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
                          app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.100.42.100
IPs:                      10.100.42.100
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30482/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.1.11:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               https/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31697/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.1.11:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Local
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                -------
  Normal  Type    54m   service-controller  LoadBalancer -> NodePort
```

Answer (score 1):

`LoadBalancer` refers to cloud load balancer, e.g ELB on AWS, Cloud Load Balancing on GCP. If you are running your own cluster on your machine, you can change the `type: LoadBalancer` to `type: NodePort` and access your ingress controller via < node ip>:<node port#>.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. With that, now the 'ingress-nginx-controller' got CLUSTER-IP and no external-ip. this cluster cluster-ip only internaly known by cluster. it con not accessed from out side of cluster event from 192.168.1.x.

Comment: You access the service like 192.168.1.x:<node port #>, and you can ONLY do this within the private network, **not** from the Internet. Can you post the output of `kubectl describe service ingress-nginx-controller --namespace ingress-nginx` to your question.

Comment: Edited @gohmc, please check

Comment: You also need to update `externalTrafficPolicy` to `Cluster`.  After that you should be able to reach your ingress controller with `curl 192.18.1.67:30482`

Comment: @gohmc .. I think it's because i got failed when trying to deploy ingres object. I'll make another post about it. I really appreciate your helps.